I logged in with Identity Server4 and I change subdomain, I want to stay logged in - .NET Core and Angular
In .NET Core 6 using Identity Server 4 password flow, Angular, I log in successfully using a valid user name and password and store the token to local storage.
Now I want to allow logged in user to switch domain to use another app using the same credentials without having to login again.
But when I redirect to the new domain (subdomain), local storage changed, so the user can't be logged in.
I need the authenticated user to switch to multiple subdomains using the same token.
